# ISP blocked routers: chap authentication failed

Tags: linux, isp, router, pppoe

Some greedy ISP blocked our routers in vise versa country, routers worked fine about 2 years. First type of blocking was by ttl, and second type now. Waking up in the morning I found a line in the log of router: `chap authentication failed`. I asked the neighbors, they have the same issue. I conclude that the problems in the settings disappear, not the first time to set up. I am sure that the ISP has blocked 99%. And ISP is monopolist. Type of connection PPPoE. 
How can I get around this? How ISP can determine what i try login to AC via router? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Switch provider. That's it. Or buy the necessary router.

Comment: ISP is monopolist. Every month buy new router? Device worked fine 2 or more years. All routers different manufacture, about ~10, stopped working at one time.

Comment: It can't be that monopolistic. As you said all routers are disabled by the ISP. But how could you ask questions here without Internet connection? So you obviously got alternatives. See David's answer, too.

Comment: I have alternatives use internet connection without routers! I repeat topic title: ISP blocked routers. This mean that i can not connect to ISP via router, but i can via usual host with windows or linux. Although in Linux similar I have not tried. But I think should work. Otherwise it is breach of contract on the provision of telecommunications services.

Comment: Cool. So use Linux as router. Problem solved.

Comment: I think all routers devices is linux/unix based devices. I have Asus W500GL. He have busybox, iptables and etc. The question is, why for example with ubuntu I can connect to my ISP with the router not?

Answer (score 1):

Complain to the ISP. If you pay for Internet access and aren't getting it, you have an issue with them.

Comment: By law, ISP not obliged to provide access via router. And I can not change the provider, because the building is owned by a private organization that does not allow providers access to the building. One solution is 3G, but it is expensive and slow .

Comment: They are not obliged to provide access via router, that's why *you* are providing the router. They are obliged to provide access.

Comment: Support service said that prohibits the use of routers. They will not help with setup. And routers do not work in their network. They also talked when we had routers that worked fine.

Comment: If the use of routers is prohibited, then you can't use them. It's a violation of Federal law to exceed authorized access to a computer or network (18 USC 1030). (Assuming this is the United States.)